# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined jquery.dataTables.min.js:48

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

i wanted to input data to dataTables with Laravel frameworks. But then i get error.

My script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tabled').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
            url: "/bawan",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json"
        },
    "columns":[
    {"data":"id"},
    {"data":"title"},
    {"data":"nama"},
    ],})})
```

Here is the Controller.

```
function bawan(){
    $datan = pekael::join('informasi', 'informasi.user_id', '=', 'pekaels.id')->select('informasi.*', 'pekaels.*')->get();
    $data = array('data'=>$datan);
    return response()->json($datan);
}
```

Table views

```
<table class="table table-striped"  cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="tabled" align="center">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Author</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

</table>
```

I'm really new to frameworks, can somebody tells me where is my mistakes?

Comment: Check if you receive the correct json from the server.

Comment: spends a week to fix the error. and it just an word. thanks btw.